# Jira, Tomcat and JBoss behind Apache

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, jboss7.x, jira

I need to install these environment in the same machine.

**Jira : ( installer, port: 8080, tomcat-jira)

Tomcat : ( tomcat for other applications, port: 8084 )

JBoss : ( port: 8086 )

Apache2: (as a proxy, mod_proxy, port: 80)**

First I´d install Jira as a service, with their installer, so, It came with a tomcat embed, port 8080.

Then I installed apache as a proxy, It worked, I can now acces the jira like this: debian.local/jira intead of debian.local:8080.

But when I put tomcat in the same server the problems began:
I changed the tomcat ports on connectors and shutdown, but when I start it, the Tomcat from Jira goes down, both-ways.

- The question is, how "un-recommended" is to install jira as a WAR deployed on my tomcat, intead of tomcat-jira?
- What´s the best way to configure this environment? How must to be declared the CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE for this?

That´s all... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your installer-created `CATALINA_HOME/CATALINA_BASE` will probably be fine.

I would also not suggest trying to share one Tomcat instance with other applications due to potential conflicts between library versions (and also because you  won't be able to shut down one application without shutting down the other).

The immediate problem is likely that you are trying to use the same shutdown port on both Tomcat instances. In JIRA's `conf/server.xml`, you will find a line like this:

```
<Server port="8004" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

The configured port must be unique for each Tomcat instance, so you need to pick something that is not in use. (This is in addition to having a unique connector port declared in `<Connector port="8080" ...`).

If you use the same shutdown port, you will find that (say) your shutdown script for one instance ends up accidentally shutting down the other instance.