# Tomcat behind an apache proxy error on path

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jira, mod-proxy

I'm trying to configure my apache 2.2 as a proxy to some applications on a server.

tomcat-jira : Installed with Jira´s installer;
tomcat-dev : Just a container for another applications.

First, my httpd.conf is like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /jira http://dev.debian.local:8080/jira
ProxyPassReverse /jira http://dev.debian.local:8080/jira

ProxyPass /tomcat http://dev.debian.local:8088
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://dev.debian.local:8088

<Location /jira>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /tomcat>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Location>
```

So when I type http://dev.debian.local/jira it works!
But in tomcat-dev, http://dev.debian.local/tomcat, it shows the page, badbly, without styles, and when I click on manage-aps, it redirect to:

**http://dev.debian.local/manager/html** instead of **http://dev.debian.local/tomcat/manager/html** causing a 404 error.

On tomcat-jira it has a parameter to configure the application that is:

Its because is just one application, so it redirects properly. How can I do something like this on tomcat instance? Is there a context path for the tomcat root?

Comment: This question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30326153/1997073

Comment: Trie this: ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://dev.debian.local:8088

Comment: I´m already tried this, I justo forgot to update here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ProxyPass` to change the path of a web application, as you can see, usually ruins everything.

Instead, you should do either this:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat http://dev.debian.local:8088/tomcat
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://dev.debian.local:8088/tomcat
```

or this:

```
ProxyPass / http://dev.debian.local:8088
ProxyPassReverse / http://dev.debian.local:8088
```

If you take the second option, re-name your "tomcat" web application to "ROOT" (case-sensitive: use capitals, even on a cass-insensitive filesystem).